# In Luke 8:43 what is "an issue of blood"?

Tags: luke

In Luke 8:43-44 we read

> 43 ¶ And a woman having an issue of blood twelve years, which had
>   spent all her living upon physicians, neither could be healed of any,
>
> 44 Came behind him, and touched the border of his garment: and
>   immediately her issue of blood stanched.

Is there any indication as to what "issue of blood" she had?

Comment: It may be the kind described at Leviticus 15:25.

Comment: She most likely had something like [Obstetric fistula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obstetric_fistula), a terrible condition.

Comment: www.womeninthescriptures.com/2012/04/woman-with-issue-of-blood.html

Comment: Cf. Lk 8:44 : "and immediately the issuing of blood was regulated/made to stand [aright]." This might indicate menstrual blood, since, to me at least, it indicates that it was not taken away in the normal sense of infirmities, but made to 'stand aright.' As in return to the normal menstrual cycle.

Comment: Just in case there’s any confusion for OP, the word “issue” is used here in the sense of “discharge”, not in the sense of “problem”.  | @SolaGratia, I believe ιστημι here means “desist from movement” rather than having to do with being “aright”— see BDAG B1.

Comment: It's in this sense I gave the interpretation 'made to stand' (i.e. still;—'stop,' hence 'aright') (any ambiguities in what I wrote above notwithstanding).

Comment: The following phrase might be significant, except it's not certain is was a part of the original text: [ἰατροῖς προσαναλώσασα ὅλον τὸν βίον]

Nestle, E., Nestle, E., Aland, B., Aland, K., Karavidopoulos, J., Martini, C. M., & Metzger, B. M. (1993). The Greek New Testament (27th ed., Lk 8:43). Stuttgart: Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft.

Answer (score 2):

**FLOW OF BLOOD.**

Luke 8:43-44 (NIV)

> "And a woman was there who had been subject to bleeding for twelve
>   years,[a] but no one could heal her. 44 She came up behind him and
>   touched the edge of his cloak, and immediately her bleeding stopped."

Luke 8:43  (NRSV)

> 43" Now there was a woman who had been suffering from hemorrhages for
>   twelve years; and though she had spent all she had on physicians,[a]
>   no one could cure her."

Luke 8:43 New Life Version (NLV)

> A woman had been sick for twelve years with a flow of blood. (*She
>   had spent all the money she had on doctors.) But she could not be
>   healed by anyone. "

From the  renderings above of the verse it appears
 that the woman  perhaps suffered irregular menstruation or
 menstruation longer that usual. Under the Law she would be considered
 unclean during the period of her discharge. Leviticus 15:25 reads;

Leviticus 15:25  (NIV)

> “‘When a woman has a discharge of blood for many days at a time other
>   than her monthly period or has a discharge that continues beyond her
>   period, she will be unclean as long as she has the discharge, just as
>   in the days of her period."

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by other answers this would be a discharge of blood from an irregular menstrual cycle (Leviticus 15:25) which can have several physical causes:

https://www.webmd.com/women/why-is-my-period-so-random#1

Some interesting aspects of this story are:

- the Gadaran/Gerasene (the town is uncertain among scholars) woman was probably a gentile since the Gerasenes apparently were keeping pigs (Mark 5:1ff) and if she were among Jews she would be forbidden to enter the crowd in her unclean state
- she touched the fringe of Jesus' garment. It is unlikely that she would have known the connection with Malachi 4:2 but "wings" and "fringes" seem to be etymologically related. Perhaps Luke sees a connection?
- by touching Jesus' garment she would render him unclean but that does not seem to have occurred.
- for many years the woman had been the victim of for-profit health care